# Avoid double lookup when updating dictionary integer members

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, python-2.6

If a dictionary contains something to which you can hold a reference, you can default-or-update it with one dictionary lookup:

```
d.setdefault('k', []).append(2)
```

However, modifying dictionary entries in the same manner is not possible if they're numbers:

```
d.setdefault('k', 0) += 1  # doesn't work
```

Instead, you need to do two dict lookups, one for read and one for write:

```
d['a'] = d.get('a', 0) + 1
```

This doesn't seem like a great idea for dictionaries with a huge number of keys. So, is there a way to do a default-or-update operation on dictionaries containing numbers? Or, phrased another way, what's the most performant way to apply a default-or-update operation on such dictionaries?

Comment: "This doesn't seem like a great idea for dictionaries with a huge number of keys." Define "huge". Because it's probably in the hundreds of thousands.

Comment: Huge enough that dictionary index traversal is costly. If that's in the hundreds of thousands, so be it.

Comment: It's probably in the tens of millions. Not that I have any proof on hand for that...

Comment: Usually, getting items from a `dict` is O(1), so most of the time you don't have to worry about it at all.  You probably knew this already, but I don't want people reading this later to get the wrong idea; usually, the bottleneck in a program won't be that you're looking up a key in a dict more than once.

Comment: `dict` lookups only start getting slow once you start getting appreciable numbers of hash collisions - which is somewhere in the millions of entries for 32 bit systems and the trillions for 64 bit systems.

Comment: (assuming a uniform hash function, which strings do have)

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity - a very good read

Comment: Sometimes it is hard to have a good hash function that distribute keys evenly and lookup time end up somewhere between O(1) and O(n). Also for all O(1)s there is a constant in front which may matter in some cases. So the question is valid. Most languages add this to hashed key-value collections as they mature, say C++, Java, C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick test suggests that [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is about 2.5 times faster than your double-lookup (tested on Python 2.6):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> s1 = "d = dict((str(n), 0) for n in range(1000000))"
>>> timeit.repeat("d['a'] = d.get('a', 0) + 1", setup=s1)
[0.17711305618286133, 0.17411494255065918, 0.17812514305114746]
>>> s2 = """
... from collections import defaultdict
... d = defaultdict(int, ((str(n), 0) for n in range(1000000)))
... """
>>> timeit.repeat("d['a'] += 1", setup=s2)
[0.07185506820678711, 0.07294416427612305, 0.12155508995056152]
```

Comment: Though I like this idea, I think the proper test would be to do what you've done, but with a large dict instead of an empty one.

Comment: @Reinderien it makes no difference. The other commenters are right: `dict` lookup is O(1). I've modified the test setup as per your suggestion anyway, and the results are essentially identical, as expected. The same goes for a dict with ten million items (a hundred million runs out of memory and crashes Python on my machine).